# How to remove dithering from image, which was in GIF format before?

Tags: gradient, png, gif, image-quality

I tried to look in the internet, but every question and topic was about improving quality of animated GIF, however it is not in my case.

What I have is **static image with 256 colors**, it is saved in **PNG format**, but it seems like it originally was saved in GIF, because every gradient is suffered from heavy dithering.

I want to improve quality of image and get rid of dithered gradients.

Do you have something in mind what I can use to make gradients look like they supposed to do, in other words revert dithering and make smooth gradients again?

I have many images. There is 3 example areas which was affected with dithering:

[image: flower]

[image: gradient1]

[image: gradient2]

EDIT: Forget to mention beforehand, that other part of image are detailed, so I provide more examples both with dithering and details:

dithered gradient in detailed area:

[image: dithered gradient in detailed area]

thin lines:

[image: thin lines]

[image: more thin lines]

[image: another example of thin lines]

Answer (score 1):

You can get rid of the 'green dots' issue using Gaussian Blur.

A setting of 3px will kill the dots, but keep the darker 'swash'.

[image]

8px will also almost kill the swash.

[image]

On anything with detail you want to retain, then 1px is getting as far as you can take it

[image]

You might be able to regenerate some edges with a high-pass filter

single pass

[image]

two-pass
[image]

High-pass used injudiciously will give odd glowing edges like a poor HDR photo, so you need to keep your pixel radius down to try avoid it. I should have gone finer in this example.

Comment: Hm, I also have some text and thin lines, I can't combine blur for more than 1px because other part of the image will be destroyed. If, say, I use mask, then on the edge of different blurs filters border will appear. It is such pain because like 2nd and 3rd image will require a lot of blur radius, but other part of same image is very detailed. I posted there only high affected by dither areas, but the other problem, what on other part of image with a lot of details it not that visible and blur here will destroy this detailed area instead.

Comment: The best way to get a very specific answer to a very specific problem is to ask that in the first place, not add it as clarification underneath an answer someone already spent time to work through, with examples.

Comment: Try smart sharpen it deconcolves so theoretically it can undo the gaussian blur but with a statistical mean. Also try surface blur.

Comment: @Tetsujin sorry for that, I added 4 more examples with problematic details where gaussan blur will create issue. For thin lines they either become less visible, either become bolder even it I try to retain edges.

Comment: there are also "fourier-transform" based filters that may be suitable. In the context of photoshopish tasks, they are sometimes used to remove paper grain and other forms of semi-uniform noise.